# Phonemes and Chronemes

Tags: python, nlp

Is there any methodology/algorithm for computing [phonemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) and [chronemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroneme) of a word(text and not audio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://129.173.35.31/~pf/Linguistique/L2P-NeuralNetwork/TextToPhoneme1.pdf) you have all the explanation of how to compute text to phonemes using neural networks. It is a pretty complex task. Hope it helps.